# Increase labelwidth MSC package

Tags: positioning, labels

I'm using the [MSC package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/msc/manual.pdf) to draw a sequence chart. I only need *one* instance, with ingoing and outgoing (lost and found) messages. I've set up a working example suing the LaTeX compiler.

http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/msc/manual.pdfhttp://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/msc/manual.pdf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{msc}
\begin{document}
\begin{msc}{test}
\declinst{a}{}{$A$}
\found{label}{}{a}
\end{msc}
\end{document}
```

which gives this result

[image]

The label i need is quite long and complicated, so I need to make the distance between the circle and the arrow longer, so there's place. I've looked at the documentation, and tried inserting various values at the `pos`, `labelpos` and `placement` optionals, but without any luck.

How can I make the label longer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, a few hours actually, I finally figured out how to do it!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{msc}
\begin{document}
\begin{msc}{test}
 \drawframe = 
\declinst{a}{}{$A$}
\selfmesswidth = 5cm

%First outgoing
\lostsymbolradius = 0px
\lost[1]{label}{}{a}
\nextlevel
\nextlevel

%First receiving
\lostsymbolradius = 0px
\found[1]{label2}{}{a}
\nextlevel
\nextlevel

%Second outgoing
\lostsymbolradius = 0px
\lost[1]{label3}{}{a}

\end{msc}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the setting `\setlength{<some parameter>}{<length>}`, you can change the default settings as you wish. Here, I changed the `\selfmesswidth` parameter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{msc}
\begin{document}
\begin{msc}{test}
\setlength{\selfmesswidth}{3cm}
\setlength{\envinstdist}{3.5cm} % According to the above one
\declinst{a}{}{$A$}
\found{Very long label}{}{a}
\end{msc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the distance between environments and nearest instance line should be adjusted accordingly as I did in `\setlength{\envinstdist}{3.5cm}`.

Comment: What is the difference between `\setlength{\selfmesswidth}{3cm}` and `\selfmesswidth = 5cm` ? :)